# Crons setup, Amasty's SMTP Email Settings extension installed and working but no Order Confirmation Emails going out

Tags: cron, order-email, cronjobs

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
SMTP Email Settings extension by Amasty
```

We had Amasty install the 'SMTP Email Settings' extension which appears to be working = when doing a test - it says:

**Connection Successful!**

and also **a test Email is sent and received in the Email account**.

However, ***no Order Confirmation Emails are going through***.

I've raised this with our hosting support who says:

Note that the Cron Jobs are fully functional and being executed. And you can confirm the same from the Cron Log on the server for the executed cron jobs.

These were executed just a minute ago:

```
Sep 1 03:56:01 node1340 CROND[9854]: (myWEBSITE) CMD (/usr/local/bin/ea-php74/php74/root/usr/bin/php /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null)
Sep 1 03:56:01 node1340 CROND[9855]: (myWEBSITE) CMD (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log)
```

We investigated the issue with the outgoing emails from your website at https://www.myWEBSITE.com - the SMTP extensions test function, sends a message successfully as we can verify from the Exim log message below:

```
2021-09-01 10:32:30 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW <= user@ourdomain.com H=(localhost) [45.79.17.125]:34314 P=esmtpa A=dovecot_login:user2@ourdomain.com S=566 T="Amasty SMTP Email Test Message" for myEmail@randomdomain.com
2021-09-01 10:32:30 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW
2021-09-01 10:32:30 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW Sender identification U=orchidaf D=5280flowers.com S=user2@ourdomain.com
2021-09-01 10:32:30 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW SMTP connection outbound 1630492350 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW 5280flowers.com myEmail@randomdomain.com
2021-09-01 10:33:17 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW => myEmail@randomdomain.com R=smarthost_dkim T=remote_smtp_smart_dkim H=smtp.antispamcloud.com [38.109.53.37] X=TLS1.2:AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes C="250 OK id=1mLNYO-000DId-KP"
2021-09-01 10:33:17 1mLNXs-0000fd-QW Completed
```

However, when we place a test order on your website and set the recipient's email address to a Gmail account of ours, the website does not send the message and there is no sign of it in the Exim log. We also ensured that Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending Settings -> Disable Email Communications is set to No and the SMTP details are correct.

We reckon the Magento 2 application requires additional configuration to start using the SMTP extension for its order confirmation emails, as far as we can see, all the necessary settings are correctly adjusted already but the issue persists.

**Is there something I forgot to turn the sending of the Order Confirmation Emails ON?**

---

---

Updated on September 2nd, 2021:

I have loaded a new template via `Marketing > Communications > Email Templates --> Add New Template`for both:

```
New Order
New Order for Guest
```

When adding the New Order Template - I've tested with a Magento generic one and also with one called:

**New Order (Smartwave/port)** --> this one loads the Template but when I try to load the following one:

New Order for Guest (Smartwave/porto)

It gives this Error:

> Attention
>
> The template did not load. Please review the log for details.

**Any which way, I've placed a test order with the new templates but *still no Order Confirmation Email coming through.***

Other settings I've checked:

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System
```

> Disable Email Communications = NO
> Host: Our mail host
> Port (25) = 25

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails
```

Under General Settings tab, chose Asynchronous sending to **Disable**

Under Order tab Enabled to **Yes**

```
Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
```

and checked that "Sales Representative" Email address is correct.

I checked the **exception.log**:

```
{"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Incorrect authentication data

 at /home/ourWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/amasty/smtp/Model/Transport.php:185)"} []
[2021-08-30 04:38:34] main.CRITICAL: Incorrect authentication data

 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Incorrect authentication data

[2021-09-02 09:09:04] main.CRITICAL: Email template '' is not defined. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Email template '' is not defined. at /home/ourWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php:225)"} []

[2021-09-02 11:17:45] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error at /home/ouWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"} []
```

**What does that mean?**

**system.log** has the following:

```
[2021-09-02 11:38:11] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
```

Comment: I've checked the Amasty module and based on your exception could be that there's no email template assigned for it, usually an email template is declared inside design\frontend\Vendor\Vendor\Magento_Sales\email\order_new.html, could be that a setup:static-content:deploy -f could do the trick, since maybe Magento has to write the email template in the static-content

Comment: @Alan Zavagli Thank you for that suggestion. I am making a backup now and will try it right after that. The interesting thing is that when I put a Comment on an already placed order in Admin and tick the option for 'Notify Customer by Email' - I get an Error message which says: www.ourWEBSITE.com says INCORRECT AUTHENTICATION DATA. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Amasty gives a tab, is the email issue for all the queued Email inside the module "Email log" in admin?

Comment: @Alan Zavagli You are right - Amasty has a Sent Emails Log. Next to all the orders it says: Failed and when I click on View - it just opens a page which says: "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content." That's not really a good Error message though.

Comment: For the SMTP Settings you're setting up: Stores -> Configuration -> Amasty -> SMTP Email settings and on the click of click and save connection is working all fine right?

Comment: @AlanZavagli Yes - that works and it even shows 'Successfully Sent' in the 'Sent Emails Log' but I think you mean Amasty (from the left) and then SMTP  Email Settings --> Configuration, right? Our hosting confirmed this is correct and yes - Save and Check connection says 'Connection Successful!' and Email is sent and received in my Email Inbox.

Comment: So there's even a debug mode with the SMTP Module, you could try to enable that  in the configuration to see if it gives more info https://ibb.co/Tgh51Rn , i've tryed setting up something strange and gives pretty detailed info

Comment: @Alan Zavagli I have just done php magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: So the Enable Debug Mode = Yes but when I go into Amasty --> SMTP Email Settings --> Debug Log - it only shows "Error sending e-mail: Incorrect authentication data" with no more information.